# Testing if a day of data is an outlier

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, outliers

I have a time series which exhibits a relatively similar behavior from one day to another. I want to know if a specific day of the time series is an outlier in the sense that it significantly differs from a usual day of the time series.

I am new to statistical analysis, however I have the impression that this problem can be phrased as a hypothesis testing problem, where the null hypothesis is that this day of data has been generated from a similar model as a usual day of the time series.

From the questions on Cross Validated on seemingly related topics like this one:
[Testing for statistically significant difference in time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25228/testing-for-statistically-significant-difference-in-time-series)
or that one:
[Hypothesis testing and significance for time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17881/hypothesis-testing-and-significance-for-time-series)
an explicit model for a usual day seems necessary, is that true? If yes, and supposing that I build a good enough model, what would be an appropriate way to test this hypothesis? Are there other ways to tackle this problem?

Thanks for your help.